# MassTransit: specify uri with virtualhost

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using **MassTransit** with **RabbitMQ** and I would like to take advantage of **RabbitMQ** virtual hosts. Other apps in my organization (not using MassTransit) have a convention of setting up virtual hosts for environments i.e. "myapp" and "myappUAT". 
I need to follow this convention, but I can't figure out how to specify a virtual host in my MassTransit uri.

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rabbitmq://localhost/vhost_name/queue_name` is all you need. We use vhosts for most things, and just try to keep it simple :)

You can see the code pulling it out here: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/v2.7.2/src/Transports/MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq/RabbitMqEndpointAddress.cs#L167

Comment: What if there are no vhosts? And I want to send to a direct exchange with a routing key for example? Following should work because I tested it and it sends to the exchange and not the queue: `rabbitmq://localhost/exchange_name`